# Set-associative TLB on Rocket Chip

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to address if Rocket Chip Generator supports a set-associative TLB (both for L1 and L2 TLB) but I cannot find any straightforward code about that in `RocketCore.scala` or `PTW.scala`. On the other hand changing the associativity of the Caches in `HellaCache.scala` is pretty straight-forward.

From my understanding L1 TLB is fully-associative and L2 TLB is direct-mapped.

Is there a straightforward way to change the set-associativity of the TLB on Rocket Chip that I am missing? If not, are there any resources that you could provide in order to help me add these features in Rocket Chip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the configurable L1/L2 TLB on Rocket Chip myself, my code is upstream and merged in the official [Rocket Chip repository](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip).

In order to change the associativity and size of the L1 TLB you can tweak  `nTLBSets, nTLBWays` in `/src/main/scala/rocket/HellaCache.scala`(only power of 2 sets/ways are allowed for now).

For the L2 TLB, you can tweak `nL2TLBSets, nL2TLBWays` in `/src/main/scala/rocket/RocketCore.scala`.